# Mesos, Docker and GRE Tunneling

Tags: docker, tunnel, mesos, bridge, openvswitch

I'm running Mesos Cluster with docker as the container solution.
I have tried Open vSwitch with dockers, with GRE Tunneling and VLANs across hosts.
I'm trying to use this VLANs setup on Mesos - Still a WIP.

Now my doubts are

1. Is it possible to use GRE Tunneling on linux bridges - so that i can use the setup with docker0 bridge itself without using Open vSwitch.
2. If GRE Tunneling is possible, what is the possibility of VLANs. Can docker can be configured to get launched on particular VLAN on the docker0 bridge.
3. If Open vSwitch is the only solution for the above two - The ports created are not destroyed automatically, after the docker gets killed - like in docker0 bridge. Any solutions are ideas on this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This post might help you: http://wiredcraft.com/blog/multi-host-docker-network/

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will go through the post completely. I'm waiting for docker native integration with OVS

Comment: I haven't used openvswitch yet however I will give a shoutout to flannel. It was relatively easy to get working properly, the documentation is decent, and it has the option to do the functional equivalent of vlan tags.

Comment: Seems cool,let me give a try on it. Thanks Ryan